# Android 4.1.2 findViewById return null

Tags: android

I have an app that only in some device with android 4.1.2 crashes with a NullPointerException in the `setVisibility`:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
        if (mDocumento.getPathPdfDevice()==null) {
           getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnBigDownloading).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
}
```

But in all other device works fine.

There is only one layout loaded like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnBigDownloading"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".30" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/btnBigDownloadingProgress"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, what's the null pointer to?  If there's a NullPointerException that means one of the values in that line is undeclared or equal to null.  Are you sure that when this code executes, `btnBigDownloading` actually exists?

Comment: i've added the layout.
but as i said the same code works fine (no nullpointer) in other version (from 2.3.3 to 4.4).. the getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnBigDownloading) return the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a really good idea to do that in onCreateOptionsMenu().

A proper solution would be to create some methods that would show the progressBar when your data is loading and call them from onPrepareOptionsMenu()

```
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layour.your_layut, container, false);
    progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.btnBigDownloading);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu);
    showProgressBar();

}

private void showProgressBar(){
    if (mDocumento.getPathPdfDevice()==null && progressBar()!=null) {
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason is that in those devices, the onCreateOptionsMenu() method is being triggered before the onCreateView() method is called. The best way to get around this would be to include your if-else logic within the onCreateView() method to ensure that the layout is inflated before this condition is checked.

Comment: i've try but the log says that the order of method was right